# arrange operators in array such that sum equal to given result

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given an array A, suppose `{5, 5, 4, 3, 7}`, use operation `{*, /, + -}` on `5, 5, 4, 3` and get the result as `7`. If it is possible, print the answer. If it is not, `return 0`.

`Answer : 5 * 5 - 4 / 3 = 7`.

I solved this using recursion, brute force, checking all the cases.

My code :

```
void check_result(int* arr, int size, char* op, int depth, int result, int val)
{
    if(depth==size)
    {
        if(val==result)
        {
             // call function to print pattern of op[]
        }
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        op[depth]='+';
        check_result( arr+1, size, op, depth+1, result, val + *arr );

        op[depth]='-';
        check_result( arr+1, size, op, depth+1, result, val - *arr );

        op[depth]='*';
        check_result( arr+1, size, op, depth+1, result, val * (*arr) );

        op[depth]='/';
        if( *arr )
            check_result( arr+1, size, op, depth+1, result, val / (*arr) );
    }
}
```

Can you tell me dynamic approach of this question, because this takes `O(4^n)` time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state should be `DP[position][currentValue]`. It means if that the neededResult can be achieved if you are at the corresponding `position` and having `currentValue`.

```
boolean rec(int position, int currentValue)
{
   if (position == lastPosition)
   {
      return currentValue == neededResult;
   } 

   if (computed[position][currentValue]) return DP[position][currentValue]; 

   boolean can = false; 
   int nextNumber = numbers[position + 1];

   //Try every operation here and call rec again
   can |= rec(position + 1, currentValue + nextNumber);
   can |= rec(position + 1, currentValue - nextNumber);
   can |= rec(position + 1, currentValue * nextNumber);
   can |= rec(position + 1, currentValue / nextNumber);

   DP[position][currentValue] = can;
   computed[position][currentValue] = true;
   return can;
}
```

You can then restore the result in another method:

```
   void restore(int position, int currentValue)
    {
       if (position == lastPosition) return;

       if (DP[position + 1][currentValue + nextNumber]) 
       { 
          cout << " + ";          
          restore(position + 1, currentValue + nextNumber);
       }
       else
       if (DP[position + 1][currentValue - nextNumber]) 
       { 
          cout << " - ";          
          restore(position + 1, currentValue - nextNumber);
       }
       else
       if (DP[position + 1][currentValue * nextNumber]) 
       { 
          cout << " * ";          
          restore(position + 1, currentValue * nextNumber);
       }
       else
       if (DP[position + 1][currentValue / nextNumber]) 
       { 
          cout << " / ";          
          restore(position + 1, currentValue / nextNumber);
       }
    }
```

P.S. This is only PSEUDOCODE. There may be errors and missed corner cases.

Comment: Here, what "can" stores is?
and one more thing, how can you bound on the size of column.
For that, i think you have to calculate the product of all values.
Am I right ??

Comment: `can` means if you can reach your goal. And yes the product is the maximum value.